# Update passwords of SQL Server 2008 R2 users via script

Tags: sql-server-2008

Background: we have an old system in production on SQL Server 2008 R2. Due to some reasons real time replication to secondary is not implemented. In case of disaster at primary, we will switch to secondary machine and restore latest available backups (except for master, msdb, model dbs). Each of our user accesses the application via SQL Server database users.

Issue: now my concern is since we will not restore master database to the secondary server, how to deal with situation where users at primary database change their passwords. When we activate the services from secondary, how to restore their passwords from primary?

One approach is that we export the users from primary and restore it on secondary. But issue with this approach is that the users creation date on secondary will be change and this will be a audit issue. Is their any way we can update passwords only?

Regards
Salman

Answer (score 0):

[dbatools](https://dbatools.io/) has very handy PowerShell cmdlet ([Copy-DbaLogin](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Copy-DbaLogin)) to do this. Just create a job to run the following script:

```
Copy-DbaLogin -Source sqlserversrc -Destination sqlserverdst -Force
```

It will copy all logins from `sqlserversrc` to `sqlserverdst` and overwrite them in case they exists (which will handle password changes).

Another option is to use SSIS and [Transfer Logins Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/transfer-logins-task?view=sql-server-2017).

If you upgrade to SQL Server 2012 (or newer) you can also consider using [contained databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases?view=sql-server-2017). Then you will not need logins on the server, because the users with passwords are part of the database itself.

Comment: Thank you, but if I use Copy-DbaLogin then either  it will create user at the destination or overwrite it if it already exist, in both cases the user creation date will be change.

Comment: No, but what's the point of doing that? The user is in the database, which will be overwritten when you restore it from the backup.

Comment: Actually each of our user has SQL Server DB id , our application use this id for user authentication . As SQL DB users resides in master table which we will not restore on secondary machines.

Comment: There is no "DB id" in SQL Server. There are logins and users. In your case "DB id" must be a login (i.e. credentials, name and password). These are stored in master database. Copy-DbaLogin copies these. Then there are users, which are logins mapped to specific database. They are saved in the user database and knows the SID of the corresponding login. There is no password for the user - the login has a password. So when you restore a database, the worst case is that you created a new user after the last backup, but this must be covered by your RPO strategy anyway.

Comment: Agree our users will be available as we restore the databases. Logins are already available in secondary. New logins will be imported via script. Only issue is logins whose passwords have been change in primary. We have 2 options

1. Delete logins from secondary  and recreate with same SID/Credentials(we have a script). But user creation date will be change (Audit Issue). 
2. Other option is that we will request only those user to change passwords once we switch to DR. If I don't get method to update logins passwords then I'll go with the second option and made it part of DR Strategy.

Comment: You missed the point. Logins are handled by Copy-DbaLogin. If the login does not exists, it gets created. If it exists, it gets overwritten. So point 1 is what it does. This also covers the case, when the password is changed on the primary. You do not need (and should not do) to delete and re-create users, because the rights granted to them will be lost! Point 2 makes no sense, because it is the same as 1, because users has no passwords! Logins does and they are already copied from the primary by Copy-DbaLogin.